# Eloquent get average for both genders from a collection without requesting again the database

Tags: laravel, collections, eloquent

I have this situation where I get a collection directly from the database and have introduced several filters already, except gender, as follows:

```
$workers = Worker::where('status','Active')->where('category','SomeCategory')->get();
```

In order to get the general age average, I get it like this:

```
$avg_age = $workers->avg('age');
```

So far so good.

Inside, the `$workers` collection, there is this column `gender`. Now I want to get the age average by gender. I have tried the following ... which doesn't work:

```
$avg_age_women = $workers->where('gender','female')->avg();
```

But this does not work since the returned value is zero.

I know I could do the same like:

```
$workers_female = Worker::where('status','Active')->where('category','SomeCategory')->where('gender','female')->get();
```

But, if I can continue working with the `$workers` collection, I think that'd be more efficient.

Is there a way to get the average of female ones right from the original `$workers` collection??? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not saying what you want to do avg on.

```
$avg_age_women = $workers->where('gender','female')->avg("age");
```